# Mongo DB - sub-collections?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql

I'm really new to MongoDb and am using it with nodeJS and the native node mongodb driver. I am having doubts about implementation. I hope you can help me:
I have this "schema", where db.pages holds the config for each section of my website:

```
db.pages = [
   {name: 'contacts', settings:{...}},
   {name: 'blog', settings:{...}, posts: "blogPosts"},
   {name: 'media', settings: {...}, posts: "mediaPosts"}
]

db.blogPosts = [
  {title: 'post1', date: '2011-10-22', author:'me', content: '...'},
  {title: 'post2', date: '2011-11-22', author:'me', content: '...'},
  {...............................................................}
];
```

What I'm doing here is, in each page, I define if I have a posts collection and, in node, when I load the page, I check if `page.posts` is defined and, if so, load the appropriate collection.

Maybe I'm wrong, but this is looking too much as a relational thing so, my idea, would be to 
put the content of `blogPosts` directly as the value for the prop `posts` of the `pages` collection, like so:

```
db.pages = [
       {name: 'contacts', settings:{...}},
       { name: 'blog', 
         settings:{...}, 
         posts: [
            {title: 'post1', date: '2011-10-22', author:'me', content: '...'},
            {title: 'post2', date: '2011-11-22', author:'me', content: '...'},
            {...............................................................}
         ]
       },
       {name: 'media', settings: {...}, posts: [...]}
    ]
```

I really think this makes much more sense, in a NoSQL environment, but I might be wrong. 
The problem I am having is that using the latter configuration, I can't seem to make nodejs treat the `posts` field as a mongo collection.

I hope this makes any sense to you and, if so, what I need to know is:

1. Am I right or wrong to think the second way is the right way?
2. How can I use node to read that 'sub-collection' as collection so I can apply a cursor and use `find()`, `sort()`, `limit()`, `skip()`, etc, on it...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First approach is better. Second approach has multiple drawbacks:

1. Each document has a size limit of 16MB. You will hit that limit and will not be able to add more blog posts
2. You cannot query and fetch individual blog posts from the disk as its all in one big document
3. if you apply this principle, then you will put all the comments also in the same pages document, further complicating it and will loose lot of flexibility

Comment: thanks, i understand points 1 and 3. I'm not sure if your 2nd point is an answer to my second question. I still don't know, if i can treat a collection's sub-collection as a 1st level one.

Comment: You can use find(), but sort(), limit(), skip() applies to documents. For example, in your second approach you cannot select latest 5 blog posts. You can find 5 pages that have latest blog posts, but will have to fetch all blog posts in those 5 pages.

Comment: ok, i almost get it. just one last question though: is there anyway that, in runtime, i can: select ONE page, turn the posts collection in a document?

Comment: i totally understand that in a case like this, things should be separated, i am just thinking about scenarios where i might find this useful, thanks

Comment: Didn't understand your last question.

Comment: hi, @SamarthBhargava I have a question that did not come out clear in the answer. Can I create sub-collections in mongo DB let's say I want a products model but I want to store products in different models lets say shoes, clothes, cutleries or electronics can I have them nested ?